# connect vcsharp windows form application with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

kindly tell if there is any way to solve the connectivity of the vcsharp with asp.net. as i am trying to run the c# windows form application on asp.net to make my website more knowlodge able. Is there any other connevtivity option besides aspnet.

Answer (score 0):

You can run web application in windows Forms application. You may embed the WebBrowser control. It makes sense, but if you want to run desktop application in a asp.net web this doesn't make sense IMO.

If you want to benefit from Rich Controls behaviors, you have web widget available within jQuery UI, BootStrap, etc.

Don't mix things

**EDITS**: According to your first comment, I'd suggest you to search for the web sdk for arcgis or an equivalent. Or You may need to reference dll available in the SDK and use web controls to display data

[Plz read this](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/native-vs-web.htm)

Comment: Bascially i am working on arcgis sdk and its working on chsarp windows form application on desktop. But nw i want to run that application on web browser so that every one can access it through website